# Is there a way to shift two logic volume position?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, swap

I had an existing Centos Stream 8 Linux System configured as automatic partition when it was installed.

The partition/logic volume layout as:

```
[root@Centos8Gateway ~]# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb           8:16   0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sdb1        8:17   0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sdb2        8:18   0 118.2G  0 part 
  ├─cl-root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─cl-swap 253:1    0   3.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─cl-home 253:2    0  64.4G  0 lvm  /home
```

As you saw, the swap logic volume was put between /(root) and /home volume.

This is very hard to manage it size and disk image clone.

My question is: Is there any way to swap the positions for my last two logic volumes in my partition table to make the partition table as:

```
[root@Centos8Gateway ~]# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb           8:16   0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sdb1        8:17   0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sdb2        8:18   0 118.2G  0 part 
  ├─cl-root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─cl-home 253:1    0  64.4G  0 lvm  /home
  └─cl-swap 253:2    0   3.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

[EDIT]

As @Romeo Ninov said, I have very limited understanding with logic volume in file system (How it works?).

The problem I met is:

If the SWAP partition (or logic volume) is not the last partition (or logic volume), when I do the disk clone (I tried three different ways such as: dd, clonezilla and balenaEtcher (on MacOS), unfortunately, no one success), I always have the last logic volume (such as "cl-home 253:2    0  64.4G  0 lvm  /home") missed in my cloned disk partition table and cloned disk never boot properly. The main season is: "there is a SWAP volume ahead of /home".

When I re-build a brand new Rocky 9 Linux system disk with manually partitioned system that put my SWAP partition as last partition in my partition table, disk clone works fine.

I do have about other handful Linux system disks were installed as automatic partition have the same issue (SWAP partition (or logic volume) is not the last partition (or logic volume)). I need to back up it to our NFS system and restore it to newer hardware machines.

That's why I need to find out a way to do the partition (or logic volume) position swap to make my SWAP partition (or logic volume) to be last one in my partition table.

If anyone have the solution, please advise!

Comment: I’m not sure I follow. What size are you trying to manage and what are you trying to clone?

Comment: Not about the partition (or logic volume) size, it is about the position in partition table.

Comment: When responding to the following, please post specific commands and their output, not only your description or interpretation. Even your best-effort interpretation may be wrong; give us hard data. Thanks. (1) "when I do the disk clone …" – How *exactly* did you do this? What device did you clone (or "clone")? (2) "I always have the last logic volume […] missed in my cloned disk" – What *exact* command(s) told you this. What was their *exact* output? (3) "The main reason is: there is a SWAP volume ahead of /home" – Is this a verbatim error message? (from what tool?) or your *guess*? or what?

Comment: There is _no way_ you could clone the LVM partition without _either_ getting all volumes inside _or_ with catastrophic data corruption. Data in LVM is not stored contiguously. So it would be _really_ important to see the actual commands you used and also “proof” of the problems with them.

Answer (score 1):

You do not understand the idea of LVM at all. Think about LV as virtual disks which do not have exact position on physical one. The order you see with `lsblk` is the order of creation of these LVs, not the position on disk, nor the position in VG.
And for the record you can extend the LV and filesystems on the fly w/o care about the visible order.

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: @cidy.long, for me it seems like you do not make the backup on proper way. Probably you do not make backup of swap partition and this is the reason of this error. Make backup of swap also and check again.